# Writing circuits in Qiskit using only Clifford and T gates

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, clifford-group, transpile

Is there a way in Qiskit to write my circuit using only Clifford and T gates (CX, S, H, T and I think also $S^\dagger$ and $T^\dagger$)? With the function compile (with aer simulator) it gives me some errors using that one as a basis. I found the function `SolovayKitaevDecomposition` that seems to work only if there is a compile with u1, u2, u3, and CX beforehand. However, I can't find any documentation about it so I'm not sure how to use it, and compile and SKD take a lot of time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to QCSE! In this site, we prefer to keep each post laser-focused to a single question. Please edit your question to either contain 1) or 2) to widely improve your chances of getting an answer. And I encourage you to open a new question with the one you end up removing from here. No problem with posting multiple questions!

Comment: Hi! Just going to second @epelaaez's excellent comment - I'm going to close until you edit so only one of your two questions is here. Please then just create a new question with your second question! Then feel free to ping me to reopen. (We do this just to make it easier to follow the threads of answers and questions, and to keep it clear what is answering what.) Welcome, and looking forward to helping you out!

Comment: Note - I simply commented out the second question and reopened - all you need to do is click 'edit' and you'll still be able to copy the text of the second question into a new question so you can get that one answered as well.

Comment: @AudenYoung thank you, I'm going to ask the second question!